# The question about commutator $[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar$ at $\hbar\rightarrow 0$ seemingly can't match with Poisson bracket $\{x,\,p\}=1$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, semiclassical, poisson-brackets

At the limit $\hbar\rightarrow 0$, all "quantum" should tend to "classical", but why is the quantum commutator $[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar$ at $\hbar\rightarrow 0$ equal to $0$, but the classical Poisson bracket is $\{x,p\}=1$? Why does it seem that $[\hat{x},\hat{p}]=i\hbar$ does not match with $\{x,p\}=1$ in the classical limit?

Comment: Source for the first statement?

Comment: @Tobias Fünke very sorry about that, in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32237/

Comment: Note that [$\hat q,\hat p] = i\hbar \{q,p\}$

Comment: I've fixed your dollar placements. Note we put them around full expressions, not individual symbols. In particular, $y=z$ shouldn't have dollar signs around the $=$.

Comment: i.e. the commutator $[x, p]=iℏ$, because $\{x,p\}=1$.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [What is the connection between Poisson brackets and commutators?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19770/2451) and links therein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a systematic invertible change of language ([Weyl correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Weyl_transform)) between Hilbert space operators and phase-space q-number variables,
$$
\hat A \leftrightarrow A, \qquad \hat B \leftrightarrow B,\\
{1\over i\hbar} [\hat A, \hat B] \leftrightarrow \{\{A,B\}\}=\{ A,B\}+ O(\hbar^2)
$$
where {{•,•}} is the [Moyal bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moyal_bracket).

In your case,
$$
{1\over i\hbar} [\hat x, \hat p] \leftrightarrow \{\{x,p\}\}=\{ x,p\}=1,
$$
where no limit has been taken. The subleading terms in ℏ happen to vanish identically.

Answer (score 3):

Well... $[x,p]=0$ for classical variables so there's no formal problem there.  The simplest quantization procedure is due to Dirac in his classic

> P.A.M.Dirac, The Principles of Quantum Mechanics

wherein he shows that, at least for the simplest observables, one should have
$$
[\hat A,\hat B]_q=i\hbar \widehat{\{A,B\}_c}
$$
i.e. the quantum commutator should be $i\hbar$ times the classical Poisson bracket of the corresponding observables.  Dirac's proof leverages the similar properties of Poisson brackets and commutators, such as antisymmetry in the arguments and the so-called derivative property.

Of course the [Groenewold van Hove theorem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/389944/36194) shows Dirac's procedure will eventually fail.