# How are the Lagrange equation and Feynmann path integral related?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, variational-principle

My question is, where could I get some more info on how the Euler-Lagrange equations are related

$$ \delta S [y(x)] =0 $$

with the Feynmann path integral formulation $ \int D[y(X)]e^{iS[y(x)]/\hbar} $

I believe that when $ \hbar \to 0$ (semiclassical), only the points that satisfy (1) contribute to the path integral.

If someone can give me more info about it :D thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classical Limit of the Feynman Path Integral](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32237/)

Comment: Also possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32110/2451