# Quantum mechanics textbooks that use path integrals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, path-integral

I'm looking for a textbook in quantum mechanics that relies heavily on Green functions and the path integral formalism to supplement my QM books. I want to do some calculations using alternative methods (path integrals, green functions, Lagrangians etc).

Comment: Feynman & Hibbs is the most lucid introduction to the subject.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19417/2451

Comment: Some lecture notes: 1. [Hitoshi Murayama](http://hitoshi.berkeley.edu/221a/pathintegral.pdf). 2. [Richard MacKenzie](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0004090). (Hat tip: CuriousOne.)

Answer (score 1):

The Feynman integral book by Johnson and Lapidus 
http://tocs.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/110841727.pdf 
tries to do everything in QM with the path integral! 
It is not quite a textbook though.

The book ''Feynman integral calculus'' by Smirnov 
http://www.amazon.com/gp/search?index=books&linkCode=qs&keywords=3540306102
*is* a textbook, and has problems and solutions.

Comment: Warning: Smirnov is a loop diagram expert and that book is about Feynman loop integral not path integral.

Answer (score 1):

Feynman's textbook "Quantum Mechanics and Path Integrals - Feynman and Hibbs" has just been reprinted and is now at a very affordable price and well worth the money.

Also could try "Path Integrals in Field Theory - U. Mosel".

Or just search online, there are lots of good lecture notes on this.

Answer (score 1):

Zinn-Justin has a book on [Path Integrals in Quantum Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198566751).

There is also Kleinert's [Path Integrals in Quantum Mechanics, Statistics, Polymer Physics, and Financial Markets](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9814273562) with extensive applications to many fields.

Schulman's book [Techniques and Applications of Path Integration](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486445283) is also very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these PDFs will help you...

Just open it in new tab and download it:

- [Feynman Path Integrals in Quantum Mechanics - KTH](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&ved=0CHAQFjAH&url=http://courses.theophys.kth.se/5A1381/reports/egli.pdf&ei=ySWuUN3uOo3PrQej14HgCg&usg=AFQjCNESnZlvczzk3jnxEy1rxT0wn5y8YQ&sig2=8YTQia8aKF5Zr9Z_1a6S3A)
- [Introduction to Quantum Field Theory](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEwQFjAD&url=http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JohnCardy/qft/qftcomplete.pdf&ei=ByauUKnGCcXprAfetYGYDg&usg=AFQjCNEM9US_BmIz1LdvvWre5Df0tp3GIg&sig2=iglhgDPKubxOJSFuML1jKw)

And if there is any problem "The Google" is always available, just use it with advanced search...