# I want to solve problems in Path integral quantum mechanics and need some suggestions for the book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, path-integral

I am looking for a book with LOTS of problems in path integral quantum mechanics. I don't need a book with lot of theory. I need a book that has MANY problems of all difficulty levels. Essentially I need a problem book. Like there is a problem book called "Problems in Physics by I.E. Irodov". Like there is Schaum's series: "3000 solved problems on ...".

Comment: [Kleinert](https://hagenkleinert.de/documents/pi/HagenKleinert_PathIntegrals.pdf) is free...

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44764/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19417/2451 and links therein.

Comment: What do you have against the [phonebook](https://www.amazon.com/Handbook-Feynman-Integrals-Christian-Grosche/dp/3662147602/ref=sr_1_1?qid=1680112747&refinements=p_27%3AChristian+Grosche&s=books&sr=1-1&text=Christian+Grosche)?