# Path integral formulation understanding

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, path-integral

I have done basic quantum mechanics and now I want to do the path integral formulation. I find Feynman's book *Path Integrals in Quantum Mechanics* difficult. Is there an easier alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19417/2451

Comment: If you've done the schrodineger formulation, you shouldn't find the Feynman book hard .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should start with *QED the strange theory of light and matter* by Feynman. Its a layman book. Once you get the intuition, get back to *Path Integrals in Quantum Mechanics*. I don't think a simpler book is there.