# Derivation of the path integral in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, path-integral

So I'm going through the path integral derivation for a general quantum system where the generalized coordinates and momentum are given as $q^i$ and $p^i$ respectively. The transition amplitude we would like to compute is given as $$U(q_a,q_b;t) = \langle q_b| e^{\frac{iHt}{\hbar}}|q_a \rangle.$$ The author mentions to insert a complete set of indeterminate states between each of the $e^{iHt}$ terms, that is, insert $$ 1 = (\prod_i\int dq_k^i)|q_k\rangle\langle q_k| $$ (partitioning them into $\epsilon$ slices). This is all fine, but the next step the author says if we consider $H$ to be a function just of $q$ we then have $$\langle q_{k+1}| f(q)| q_k\rangle = f(q_k) \langle q_{k+1}| q_k\rangle = f(q_k) \prod_i \delta(q_k^i-q_{k+1}^i). $$

This part follows nicely, but he claims that we can write it as $$\langle q_{k+1}| f(q)| q_k\rangle =f(\frac{q_k+q_{k+1}}{2})\left(\prod_i\int \frac{dp_k^i}{2\pi}\right)exp[i\sum_i p_k^i(q_{k+1}^i-q_k^i )].$$

Where does $p$ come from here and why does $q_k$ get replaced with the midpoint of $q_k$ and $q_{k+1}$? Also, where does the exponent come from and why the $2\pi$?

Comment: It is rewriting $\delta$ function as an integral: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dp}{2\pi} e^{ipx}=\delta(x)$.

Comment: GaH! How did I not see that

Comment: That solves most of my issue, but why does $f(q_k)=f(\frac{q_k+q_{k+1}}{2})$?

Comment: There is a delta function that identifies $q_k$ and $q_{k+1}$, so $f( (q_k+q_{k+1})/2)\delta(q_k-q_{k+1})=f(q_k)\delta(q_k-q_{k+1})$.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/56070/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19417/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @MengCheng Please consider converting your comments to an answer.